# What is meant by "Unknown instance" when restarting a service?

Tags: process, services, vsftpd

I am trying to get `vsftpd` file server running on Ubuntu 13.10, I'm unable to connect to the server from another network, although this other network is connected to the server's network and `ping` is working. Something is suspicious about `vsftpd` restarting, when configuring `vsftpd` I'm asked to restart it using:

```
service vsftpd restart
```

The output says: "Stop: unknown instance". I don't know what that means?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A restart job has to kill an old instance first. What is happening here is that there isn't an old copy to kill.

I advise you to try this command instead:

```
 /etc/init.d/vsftpd restart
```

Comment: I think your command worked, it returned: " 

    Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
    utility, e.g. service vsftpd restart
    initctl: Unknown job: vsftpd
     
    Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
    Upstart job, you may also use the stop(8) and then start(8) utilities,
    e.g. stop vsftpd ; start vsftpd. The restart(8) utility is also available."

Comment: Not ubuntu way.